# Deriving remainder of the division of a polynomial using two methods

Tags: polynomials

> If $f(x)=x^3+2x^2+x+2$, find the remainder when $f(x)$ is divided by $(x+2)^2$.

I tried two methods.

1. First, using polynomial long division, I got the answer $5x+10$.
2. I factored the polynomial as $f(x)=(x^2+1)(x+2)$.

So, $\dfrac{f(x)}{(x+2)^2}=\dfrac{x^2+1}{x+2}$

But this one gives $5$ as the remainder, with long division.

Why is the second method incorrect or what did I miss?

Comment: Both are incorrect.  Check your long division, there's only a sign error there...  In the second case, how did you conclude $5$ is the remainder, unless you assume divisor is $(x+2)$, which is obviously incorrect?

Comment: @Macavity, sorry it was a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing two different operations. Try to understand this with numbers. If you divide $10$ by $4$ you get a reminder $2$. That's different then when you divide both by $2$ first, and the reminder of $5$ divided by $2$ is $1$. So in the first case you write $$p(x)=(x+2)^2q(x)+r(x)$$
In the second case, $$\frac{p(x)}{(x+2)}=(x+2)q(x)+r'(x)$$